# How do I run npm commands on existing docker container with exec?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, exec

I have a local Node (node:latest) image being run on docker (without any access to the original image, I only can change the tag of the image if required)

I need to call an "npm install -g some_app" on that node with exec, but docker exec call results in

```
exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"npm\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Generally you should add this to your application’s `package.json` file, re-run `docker build`, and delete and recreate your container.  Deleting containers is extremely routine and manually installing software via a `docker exec` shell is just asking to lose work.

Comment: @David Maze As I said, there is no option to change image (except for the tag), it's being run by another application

Comment: @LeYar can you share your `docker exec command` and another thing verify `        "Cmd": [  "/bin/sh"` this sectio using `docker inspect image_name`